Infinite loop in foreach in pgfplots axis?
I'm trying to generate a staircase plot by computing the coordinates with a foreach loop, but the compilation never stops and gives nothing. A minimal example follows:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot[const plot]
        coordinates {
          \foreach \x in {1, 2, ..., 5} {
            ({\x - 1}, {\x * sqrt(\x)}) ({\x}, {\x * sqrt(\x)})
          }
        };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


@vondbrand foreach + axis => expansion issue (?)
take a look here

Don't you have a stray opening square bracket after \begin{axis}? And please test code before testing. You have a typo in the preamble, too.

@JeT Though that answer seems to say it works in coordinates? Or have I just misunderstood? (I think I must have misunderstood ....)

@cfr, thanks! Fixed. Same trouble.

Replacing with \pgfplotsinvokeforeach gives the same problem.

Besides removing the blanks in the set I‘m suspicious this can work at all. I don‘t recall the coordinates-statement has a memory function, as you would have when writing to a file. So you most likely need to do exactly that: perform calculations and storage outside of this code. // BTW, why are you kind of duplicating coordinates besides the first and the last?

A workaround is to create a command to fill in coordinates outside:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18}

\begin{document}

  \newcommand\coords{}
  \foreach \x in {1, 2, ..., 5} {
    \xdef\coords%
      {\coords ({\x - 1}, {\x * sqrt(\x)}) ({\x}, {\x * sqrt(\x)})}%
  }

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot[const plot]
        coordinates {
          \coords
        };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Yes, an external program could create data to be slurped in, but I'd prefer a self-contained solution.
This seems to me to be the cleanest way to solve this type of problem. Even I  (a rank newbie at LaTeX programming) understands what is going on here. Just the wart that it tramples on \coords. How do I miss LISPy (gensym)...

Instead of \foreach (not expandable and not usable inside coordinates) you can use an expl3 loop, here \int_step_function:nN which I provide a user level alias.
An ad hoc function returning the desired coordinate pair is defined. We also need to expand the loop before passing it to \addplot.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\staircasecoords}{m}{%
  (\fpeval{#1-1},\fpeval{#1*sqrt(#1)}) (#1,\fpeval{#1*sqrt(#1)})
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \stepfunction \int_step_function:nnN
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \expanded{
      \noexpand\addplot[const plot]
        coordinates { \stepfunction{1}{5}{\staircasecoords} };
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Without \expanded, you can use a local macro (and no \xdef)
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\staircasecoords}{m}{%
  (\fpeval{#1-1},\fpeval{round(#1*sqrt(#1),4)}) (#1,\fpeval{round(#1*sqrt(#1),4)})
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \stepfunction \int_step_function:nnN
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \edef\coords{\stepfunction{1}{5}{\staircasecoords}}
    \addplot[const plot] coordinates { \coords };}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Here I added rounding, just to show how to limit the number of significant digits. With this approach, \coords will not be defined outside the tikzpicture. Its value turns out to be
(0,1) (1,1) (1,2.8284) (2,2.8284) (2,5.1962) (3,5.1962) (3,8) (4,8) (4,11.1803) (5,11.1803)


+1 Nice approach

Here is one way to do it.
1. External data generation
For simplicity I used R, with function cat() concatenating all required characters and calculations, from the command line of a R-term:
> for(x in 1:5) cat( "(", x-1, ",", x*sqrt(x), ") ", "(", x, ",", x*sqrt(x), ")")
( 0 , 1 )  ( 1 , 1 )( 1 , 2.828427 )  ( 2 , 2.828427 )( 2 , 5.196152 )  ( 3 , 5.196152 )( 3 , 8 )  ( 4 , 8 )( 4 , 11.18034 )  ( 5 , 11.18034 )> 

2. Feeding it to pgfplots
There are several ways to do it, with using table instead of coordinates might be the most versatile approach.
Either copy the R-result into macro \mydata or directly into the addplot:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18}

\def\mydata{( 0 , 1 )  ( 1 , 1 )( 1 , 2.828427 )  ( 2 , 2.828427 )( 2 , 5.196152 )  ( 3 , 5.196152 )( 3 , 8 )  ( 4 , 8 )( 4 , 11.18034 )  ( 5 , 11.18034 )}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot[const plot]
        coordinates {
%          \foreach \x in {1, 2, ..., 5} {
%            ({\x - 1}, {\x * sqrt(\x)}) ({\x}, {\x * sqrt(\x)})
%          }
            \mydata
        };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Unfortunately \input(loopdata.txt) doesn't work here, which brings me back to table, using filecontent, too.
